# get the src from img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax to grab a page.

withing a table lies an imagesrc i want to grab.. It is wrapped around an A tag with a  class name

i use the following

```
$response.find(".infobox tr").each(function(){
$a=$(this).find(".image").html();
}
```

but it returns the image tag `<img src="http://uwww.domain.com.au/image.jpg" height="333" width="256">`

i have tried the attr("src") and other methods but to no avail.. is there a trick i am missin

Comment: You should post more of your code, because it's definitely the "src" attribute that you want, and getting it with `.attr()` is correct. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: You probably should read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
$a=$(this).find(".image img").attr("src")
```

Comment: Well that'll correctly set "$a" to the "src" attribute value, but until @Alessandro shows us what "$a" is and how it is used, we don't really know what's wrong with his code.

Comment: The problem will occur if there MORE than one `img` in `.image` class

Comment: exactly - but we can't advise on how to fix it until we see what that `$a` is supposed to do. Or it could be that there's just on `<img>` tag in his HTML, and that `$a` is being set correctly already, and the error is completely unrelated to this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$a=$(this).find(".image img").attr("src")
```

Comment: this works perfectly.. i think my mistake was having the html() at the end..

cheers